# c application server socket connection is hanging

Tags: c, sockets

I'm connecting to a server in my C application using a socket connection. Once in a while the server just wont return anything. I mean NOTHING. So my application hangs. I've tried using a timeout:

```
signal(SIGALRM, timeouthandler);
alarm(myTimeout);

(socket and connection logic)...    

alarm(0);
```

but it still hangs and doesn't return to the script. A co-worker said it might be because I'm using a blocking connect. But from what I'm reading you set a connection to non-blocking after the connection is already made.

What should I look into?

Comment: Make sure the server hasn't deadlocked (multithreading, etc) and then make sure that the server's sending buffer hasn't filled-up. For that, ensure that your client has read everything the server claims it sent.

Comment: I'm working with a server that is set up to no return anything to simulate in the wild when a connection is left hanging. So I'm looking for things I can do in my code to kill the connection and move on if a timeout has been reached

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your client's `read()` doesn't return because the server isn't sending anything. If you want to go the asynchronous route and allow for timeouts, use `select()`. You can go with a more elaborate event-driven framework like libuv, but just start with simple multiplexing for now.

Comment: No, my connect() statement is hanging.

Comment: `connect` won't hang forever. The timeout's about 30s on most platforms. If you want your application to be responsive while you're going through the unavoidable TCP waiting, your coworker's right that you should use non-blocking connect. It's perfectly OK to set non-blocking before issuing `connect`, which will return immediately. The socket will be signalled readable when the connect is done (via `select`—you do have a select loop?) It's possible to use alarms instead of `select`, but it's hardly popular!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'What should I look into?'

As a debugging tool, I find Wireshark is useful when debugging socket connections.  I've done a few socket applications in C, and sometimes it comes down to the TCP stack library doing wonky things, and Wireshark can sometimes uncover that.

Hope this helps,